# How to Unit Test a void method with a Task inside

Tags: c#, unit-testing, task-parallel-library

I have a graphic method CancelChanges() used and called by a ViewModel.
I want to test this method but we have a Task inside.
We use a Task to not freeze the UI.
My test method needs to wait the result of this Task to check the result.

The code is:

```
public override void CancelChanges()
{
        Task.Run(
            async () =>
                {
                    this.SelectedWorkflow = null;
                    AsyncResult<IncidentTypeModel> asyncResult = await this.Dataprovider.GetIncidentTypeByIdAsync(this.Incident.Id);

                    Utils.GetDispatcher().Invoke(
                        () =>
                            {
                                if (asyncResult.IsError)
                                {
                                    WorkflowMessageBox.ShowException(
                                        MessageHelper.ManageException(asyncResult.Exception));
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    this.Incident = asyncResult.Result;
                                    this.Refreshdesigner();
                                    this.HaveChanges = false;
                                }
                            });
                });
}
```

And my test method:

```
/// <summary>
///     A test for CancelChanges
/// </summary>
[TestMethod]
[TestCategory("ConfigTool")]
public void CancelChangesTest()
{
    string storexaml = this._target.Incident.WorkflowXamlString;
    this._target.Incident.WorkflowXamlString = "dsdfsdgfdsgdfgfd";

    this._target.CancelChanges();

    Assert.IsTrue(storexaml == this._target.Incident.WorkflowXamlString);
    Assert.IsFalse(this._target.HaveChanges);
}
```

How can we do to have my test that is waiting the result of the Task?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you make the return type `Task`? Also, it looks like you don't need `Task.Run` because `GetIncidentTypeByIdAsync` is async (and hopefully non-blocking).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make the `CancelChanges` method return a `Task`, and then await this or set up a continuation in the test method. Some this like

```
public override Task CancelChanges()
{
    return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            // Do stuff...
        });
}
```

notice the change from `Task.Run` to `Task.Factory.StartNew`. This is a better way of starting tasks in such cases. Then in the test method

```
[TestMethod]
[TestCategory("ConfigTool")]
public void CancelChangesTest()
{
    string storexaml = this._target.Incident.WorkflowXamlString;
    this._target.Incident.WorkflowXamlString = "dsdfsdgfdsgdfgfd";
    this._target.CancelChanges().ContinueWith(ant => 
        {
            Assert.IsTrue(storexaml == this._target.Incident.WorkflowXamlString);
            Assert.IsFalse(this._target.HaveChanges);
        });
}
```

You could also mark the test method as `async` and use `await` in the test method to do the same thing.

I hope this helps.

Comment: You could also use `this._target.CancelChanges().Wait()` if you want to do it synchronously.

Comment: Thanks for your help. We use this version now. It is working and the UI is not freezed

Comment: I recommend that anyone with this problems takes 5 minutes to read this blog http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/10/24/10229468.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I would take the refactoring one step further, and if possible avoid using `Task.Run`. Since all you do is await and then invoke work on the UI Thread, I would do the following:

```
public override Task CancelChanges()
{
     this.SelectedWorkflow = null;
     AsyncResult<IncidentTypeModel> asyncResult =       await    this.Dataprovider.GetIncidentTypeByIdAsync(this.Incident.Id);
     if (asyncResult.IsError)
     {          WorkflowMessageBox.ShowException(MessageHelper.ManageException(asyncResult.Exception));
     }        
    else
    {
         this.Incident = asyncResult.Result;
         this.Refreshdesigner();
         this.HaveChanges = false;
     }
   });
 });
}
```

And the test method:

```
[TestMethod]
[TestCategory("ConfigTool")]
public async Task CancelChangesTest()
{
  string storexaml =   this._target.Incident.WorkflowXamlString;
  this._target.Incident.WorkflowXamlString = "dsdfsdgfdsgdfgfd";

  var cancelChanges = await  this._target.CancelChanges();

  Assert.IsTrue(storexaml == this._target.Incident.WorkflowXamlString);
  Assert.IsFalse(this._target.HaveChanges);
}
```